# Errors when trying to implement Swipe Views in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Sorry for the code dump, I'm new to android and don't know where the problem is. I'm trying to implement swipe views in my android app and I'm having some trouble. I tried following [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQekzaAgIlQ) but I'm getting some errors. I want the tabbed interface in my `MainActivity`

Here is my `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.loomius.loomius;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new FixedTabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    }   
}
```

I'm getting this error for `getSupporFragmentManager()`

```
'FixedTabsPagerAdapter(android.app.FragmentManager)' in 'com.loomius.loomius.FixedTabsPagerAdapter' cannot be applied to '(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager)'
```

and here is my `FixedTabsPagerAdapter.java`

```
package com.loomius.loomius;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import values.MatchesFragment;
import values.SuggestedSongsFragment;
import values.UserFragment;


public class FixedTabsPagerAdapter  extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    public FixedTabsPagerAdapter (FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                return new SearchFragment();
            case 1:
                return new UserFragment();
            case 2:
                return new MatchesFragment();
            case 3:
                return new SuggestedSongsFragment();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    Context context;

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle (int position) {
        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                return context.getResources().getString(R.string.search_frag_title);
            case 1:
                return context.getResources().getString(R.string.user_frag_title);
            case 2:
                return context.getResources().getString(R.string.matches_frag_title);
            case 3:
                return context.getResources().getString(R.string.sugg_frag_title);
            default:
                return null;

        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error for the return type `Fragment` in the overridden method `getItem`

```
'getItem(int)' in 'com.loomius.loomius.FixedTabsPagerAdapter' clashes with 'getItem(int)' in 'android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter'; attempting to use incompatible return type
```

I put the `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` widget in my `activity_main.xml` right below the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` widget.

Comment: change to `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` and `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your FixedTabPagerAdapter constructor, you are trying to catch the reference of `android.app.FragmentManager` instance while passing the fragment manager of type `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`which are two different classes.

Change the type of FragmentManager in your FixedTabPageAdapter to `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` and it should fix the issue.

Comment: I did this and it removed all the errors but the app crashes when I try to open that activity in my device. Why?

Comment: Its hard to tell without seeing logs, can you post the crash logs here?

Answer (score 0):

For sliding pages with tabs do following.

Download or copy following two files on github and paste your project.
this is same as on developers.google.com except setDistributeEvenly method.

https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java

https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabStrip.java

activity_main.xml

```
<your.package.name.SlidingTabLayout
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
 </your.package.name.SlidingTabLayout>

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

MyAdapter.java  (Here i used two pages only)

```
class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    String[] title = {"All","Favourites"};
    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment=null;
         if (position==0)
            fragment= new All();
             if (position==1)
                fragment= new Favourites();
        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
     public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
       @Override
       public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
             return title[position];
    }
 }
```

tab_view.xml  (view of tab only , if you want u can also use ImageView here)

```
   <FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        />
   </FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
  private SlidingTabLayout tabLayout;
 private ViewPager pager;
 tabLayout= (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
 pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
 tabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.tab_view,R.id.tab_title);
 MyPagerAdapter adapter =  new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
 pager.setAdapter(adapter);
 tabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
 tabLayout.setViewPager(pager);
```